# Vuejs & Firestore - How to Update when Data Changes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I've gone through a bunch of tutorials and docs but cannot seem to be able to update on page when data changes in Firestore (NOTE: not Firebase)

Heres what I have currently which is working fine except if data changes in the DB it is not reflected on the page itself unless I refresh. Code below is within script tags:

```
 import { recipeRef } from '../../firebase';
 export default {
 data() {
  return {
    recipes: []
  }
},
firestore: {
  recipes: recipeRef
},
created() {
  db.collection('recipes').get().then((onSnapshot) => {
    this.loading = false
    onSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      let data = {
        'id': doc.id,
        'name': doc.data().name
      }
      this.recipes.push(data)
    })

  })
}
```

I'm not using Vuex. Adding data, editing and reading works fine. Just not reflecting changes once data has changed. Maybe there is a life cycle hook Im supposed to be using? For "`onSnapshot`" - Ive tried "`snap`", "`querySnapshot`" etc. No luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `get()` and just replace with snapshot - like so

```
created() {
  db.collection('recipes').onSnapshot(snap => {
      let foo = [];
      snap.forEach(doc => {
       foo.push({id: doc.id, name: doc.data().name})

       });
    }
});
```

Comment: does not mean to hit database which is gonna be costly ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the firestore API, but glancing through the docs, it looks like calling `get()` is how you query a single time. Where you have `onSnapshot` should really be `querySnapshot` -- that is, the results of a one query. See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

versus:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

So to get live updates, it looks like you need to create a listener, like so:

```
db.collection('recipes')
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // Find existing recipe in this.recipes
            // and swap in the new data
        });
    }, function(error) {
        // handle errors
    });
```

I think you will need to add that listener *in addition* to the `get()` query you are currently doing. Hope this helps!